# Use System.Uri in strongly typed configuration class for ASP.net core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, uri

In our `AspNetCore 2.2` app, we make use of strongly typed classes for configuration sections,
following the pattern:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyConfigSettings(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    MyConfigSettings myConfigSettings = new MyConfigSettings();
    configuration.Bind("MyConfig", myConfigSettings);
    services.AddSingleton(myConfigSettings);
    return services;
}
```

Now the `MyConfigSettings` class looks like this:

```
public class MyConfigSettings
{
    #pragma warning disable CA1056 // Uri properties should not be strings      
    public string HostUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an easy way to use `System.Uri` instead of `System.String` as type for HostUrl, so that we don't need to suppress the Roslyn analyzer warning [CA1056](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1056-uri-properties-should-not-be-strings?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: If it doesn't work automatically, parse the string as a URI in the property setter?

Comment: just change the property from string to Uri. The bind should take care of the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the property from `string` to `Uri`.

```
public class MyConfigSettings {        
    public Uri HostUrl { get; set; }
}
```

The bind should take care of the rest.

You can also bind to the object graph like this

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMyConfigSettings(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) {
    MyConfigSettings myConfigSettings = configuration.GetSection("MyConfig").Get<MyConfigSettings>();
    services.AddSingleton(myConfigSettings);
    return services;
}
```

> [`ConfigurationBinder.Get<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.get) binds and returns the specified type. `Get<T>` is more convenient than using `Bind`.

The preceeding code shows how to use `Get<T>` with the your example, which allows the bound instance to be directly assigned to the property.

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core: Bind to an object graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bind-to-an-object-graph)

Comment: Uri instance created by `Uri(string)` constructor differs from one desirialized in Settings/Options pattern. At least with value like `//servername/C$`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! When posing the question I had internet links in mind, I did not think about the scenario of using URIs to denote Windows paths.

Comment: This is because the ConfigurationBinder uses TypeConverters for deserialization, and in the case of Uri its the UriTypeConverter. This converter will use this constructor instead: `new Uri("//servername/C$", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);` which would result in `file://servername/C$`